# GraphEngine Scaling

Tags: graphengine

I don't see any documentation on scaling GraphEngine.

I'm confused as to how this works. I saw that there is a "distributed" mode. I can add the servers and get them to hook up, but I can't get data to be used in both places.

LocalStorage vs CloudStorage is confusing. It doesn't seem you can query on CloudStorage either (for data that might exist in multiple places).

Do you have any examples of this? I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean LINQ interfaces by "query", then currently there's no built-in support for LINQ over cloud storage. However, it should be easy to write a wrapper handler that broadcasts a query to the cloud, and let each server collect data using LINQ, then aggregated together.

Could you elaborate your scenario? It would be interesting to see how a user would like to query over a distributed cluster.

Comment: Similar to Azure Storage, in distributed mode, is there a single master, and all replicas are read only copies? How do I find the master, or how do I know my read is the most current value?

Comment: @LamonteCristo it's actually configurable. By default the data is partitioned in a share-nothing manner. You can roll your own replication scheme.

Comment: I need to find more information on that. Perhaps I can figure it out by looking at the unit tests. I saw a Git work item saying this is coming to documentation sometime...